# Tarfile - Open tar file inside tar archive and extract files out of it - python

Tags: python, tar, archive, tarfile

i have several tar archives... some of them have another tar archive inside the archive. I write a code to extract specific files out of the archive. It works so far, but when the script extract files out of a nested archive the extractet file is still a archive. But when i try to open it manuelly it says the archive is broken. When i extract the file by hand the file is valid.

```
#Files in one Folder without checking for existant files (work stable!)
import tarfile
import os, os.path
from pathlib import Path

#time 
time = "2350"

#working dir
windows = "C:/Users/Elisabeth/Desktop"
ubuntu = "/home/elisabeth/Dokumente/master/radolan_data/raw"
download_directory = "/radolan_downloads" #Directory where files will be saved

os.chdir(ubuntu + download_directory) 

#Actual Working Dir
print("Actual Working dir:", os.getcwd()) 

#All files inside Working dir
files = os.listdir()
print("Files inside this folder: ", len(files))


#Iterate through folders get tar archiv names loop through them and extract only with specified time
tar_files = [x for x in files if ".tar.gz" in x]
print("Tar files inside this folder: ", len(tar_files))
for file in tar_files:
    print("Open tar: ", file)
    tar = tarfile.open(file)
    names = tar.getnames()
    print(len(names), "files are inside the tar")
    names_f = [x for x in names if time in x]
    if len(names) == 1:
        tar_final = tarfile.open(fileobj=tar.extractfile(names[0]))
        names_final = tar_final.getnames()
        print(len(names_final), "files inside second tar")
        names_f_final = [x for x in names_final if time in x]
        tar.extractall(members=[x for x in tar_final.getmembers() if x.name in names_f_final])
        print("Finish with extraction of files: ", names_f_final)
        continue
    else:
        tar.extractall(members=[x for x in tar.getmembers() if x.name in names_f])
        print("Finish with extraction of files: ", names_f)
        continue
```

The else part works perfectly it untar the right file and the file is a readable binary file. The if part extract the file also and the name of the file is like it has to be but it says it is a archiv-type and when i open it with a archive handler it says the archive is broken?? I can't upload the tar-archive because it has several gigabytes. Maybe the problem is because i open the tar object in memory in the if part?